# Include more rows in Pivot

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am using the extension method in below link to pivot my data:
https://techbrij.com/pivot-c-array-datatable-convert-column-to-row-linq

I am including the code from the link just in case somebody finds this question in the future and the link is dead:

```
public static DataTable ToPivotTable<T, TColumn, TRow, TData>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, TColumn> columnSelector,
    Expression<Func<T, TRow>> rowSelector,
    Func<IEnumerable<T>, TData> dataSelector)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            var rowName = ((MemberExpression)rowSelector.Body).Member.Name;
            table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(rowName));
            var columns = source.Select(columnSelector).Distinct();

            foreach (var column in columns)
                table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(column.ToString()));

            var rows = source.GroupBy(rowSelector.Compile())
                             .Select(rowGroup => new
                             {
                                 Key = rowGroup.Key,
                                 Values = columns.GroupJoin(
                                     rowGroup,
                                     c => c,
                                     r => columnSelector(r),
                                     (c, columnGroup) => dataSelector(columnGroup))
                             });

            foreach (var row in rows)
            {
                var dataRow = table.NewRow();
                var items = row.Values.Cast<object>().ToList();
                items.Insert(0, row.Key);
                dataRow.ItemArray = items.ToArray();
                table.Rows.Add(dataRow);
            }

            return table;
        }
```

Referring to the example in the link, you get the pivoted data like;

```
var pivotTable = data.ToPivotTable(
              item => item.Year, 
              item => item.Product,  
              items => items.Any() ? items.Sum(x=>x.Sales) : 0);
```

My question is, how can I include more rows into this query to return for example, ProductCode as well.. `item => new {item.Product, item.ProductCode}` does not work..

---

**============== EDIT / 23 OCT 2018 ==============**

---

**Assuming my data is this;**

[image]

**With the help of the above mentioned code, I can manage to do this;**
[image]

**What I want to achieve is this (extra col: STOCKID or any other cols as well);** 
[image]

Comment: Hi Brian, just have.. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mXr9sh

The issue seems to be fetching the row names from the expression, since it's only designed to handle one row.  That can be fixed by this function:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetMemberNames<T1, T2>(Expression<Func<T1, T2>> expression)
{
    var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (memberExpression != null) 
    {
        return new[]{ memberExpression.Member.Name };
    }
    var memberInitExpression = expression.Body as MemberInitExpression;
    if (memberInitExpression != null)
    {
        return memberInitExpression.Bindings.Select(x => x.Member.Name);
    }
    var newExpression = expression.Body as NewExpression;
    if (newExpression != null)
    {
        return newExpression.Arguments.Select(x => (x as MemberExpression).Member.Name);
    }

    throw new ArgumentException("expression"); //use: `nameof(expression)` if C#6 or above
}
```

Once you have this function you can replace these lines:

```
var rowName = ((MemberExpression)rowSelector.Body).Member.Name;
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(rowName));
```

With this:

```
var rowNames = GetMemberNames(rowSelector);
rowNames.ToList().ForEach(x => table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(x)));
```

One downside of this approach is the various values for these columns get returned concatenated in a single column; so you'll need to extract the data from the strings.

---

Resulting DataTable:

(displayed as JSON)

```
[
  {
    "StockId": "{ StockId = 65, Name = Milk }",
    "Name": "3",
    "Branch 1": "1",
    "Branch 2": "0",
    "Central Branch": null
  },
  {
    "StockId": "{ StockId = 67, Name = Coffee }",
    "Name": "0",
    "Branch 1": "0",
    "Branch 2": "22",
    "Central Branch": null
  }
]
```

---

Full Code Listing

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json; //just for displaying output

public class Program 
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var data = new[] { 
            new { StockId = 65, Name = "Milk", Branch = 23, BranchName = "Branch 1", Stock = 3 },
            new { StockId = 65, Name = "Milk", Branch = 24, BranchName = "Branch 2", Stock = 1 },
            new { StockId = 67, Name = "Coffee", Branch = 22, BranchName = "Central Branch", Stock = 22 }
        };

        var pivotTable = data.ToPivotTable(
            item => item.BranchName, 
            item => new {item.StockId, item.Name},  
            items => items.Any() ? items.Sum(x=>x.Stock) : 0);

        //easy way to view our pivotTable if using linqPad or similar
        //Console.WriteLine(pivotTable);
        //if not using linqPad, convert to JSON for easy display
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pivotTable, Formatting.Indented));
    }
}   

public static class PivotExtensions
{
    public static DataTable ToPivotTable<T, TColumn, TRow, TData>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source,
        Func<T, TColumn> columnSelector,
        Expression<Func<T, TRow>> rowSelector,
        Func<IEnumerable<T>, TData> dataSelector)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        //foreach (var row in rowSelector()
        var rowNames = GetMemberNames(rowSelector);
        rowNames.ToList().ForEach(x => table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(x)));
        var columns = source.Select(columnSelector).Distinct();

        foreach (var column in columns)
            table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(column.ToString()));

        var rows = source.GroupBy(rowSelector.Compile())
            .Select(rowGroup => new
                    {
                        Key = rowGroup.Key,
                        Values = columns.GroupJoin(
                            rowGroup,
                            c => c,
                            r => columnSelector(r),
                            (c, columnGroup) => dataSelector(columnGroup))
                    });

        foreach (var row in rows)
        {
            var dataRow = table.NewRow();
            var items = row.Values.Cast<object>().ToList();
            items.Insert(0, row.Key);
            dataRow.ItemArray = items.ToArray();
            table.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }

        return table;
    }
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetMemberNames<T1, T2>(Expression<Func<T1, T2>> expression)
    {
        var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExpression != null) 
        {
            return new[]{ memberExpression.Member.Name };
        }
        var memberInitExpression = expression.Body as MemberInitExpression;
        if (memberInitExpression != null)
        {
            return memberInitExpression.Bindings.Select(x => x.Member.Name);
        }
        var newExpression = expression.Body as NewExpression;
        if (newExpression != null)
        {
            return newExpression.Arguments.Select(x => (x as MemberExpression).Member.Name);
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("expression"); //use: `nameof(expression)` if C#6 or above
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous types cannot be passed as generic parameters. Try defining your pivot key as a struct:

```
public struct PivotKey
{
    public string Product;
    public int ProductCode; // assuming your product codes are integers
}
```

This way you can take advantage of struct's default `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods implementation in terms of the equality and hash code of all the fields.

Then, define the `rowSelector` as below:

```
item => new PivotKey { Product = item.Product, ProductCode = item.ProductCode}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not particularly interested in adding one column but many. So for example besides STOCKID column what if I wanted to include CATEGORY, SUPPLIER etc. columns?

Comment: Then you'll have to add thoses fields to the *PivotKey* struct as well. If you plan to use multiple different pivot keys, you'll have to define one struct per key (ex: ProductPivotKey, BranchPivotKey, etc). If you want to allow users to dynamically define their pivot key, my solution will no work, and you'll need to work with expression trees to dynamically build `rowSelector`